# Why tailwind is not working with vue 2 and sass?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use tailwind with vue 2. Earlier I had tried using tailwind with vue 3 and I was successful.

Steps

1. I had a vue 2 project with sass, router and everything else setup.
2. I installed tailwind and its dependencies using `npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9.`
3. I created `postcss.config.js` and `tailwind.config.js`

```
// postcss
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

```
//tailwind config
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  important: true,
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Then I imported tailwind in my main sass file at the top.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Finally, I imported this in my `main.js` file, alongside other sass files.

```
// main.js
import './assets/sass/main.scss'
import './assets/sass/variables.scss'
```

It's not giving me an error. But when I'm using tailwind classes it's not working, it's just assigning that class.
I went through their docs but couldn't find anything. Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: Stupid question: did you import the scss file in your vue instance ? 
NB: important: true in tailwind config is really dangerous, be careful

Comment: I don't think we need to add scss file in vue instance (importing it in App.vue), I already imported it in the main.js file, and I am positive that my sass variables and classes are working.